# Can/Should I lay out my react web app using Fabric React Stack element?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

When I look at the documentation, seems like the [Stack element](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/stack) is the one I should use to lay out my app.

I want a basic layout with a header, a footer and a main section. Header and footer should have fixed heights. Main section must grow/shrink in height. All must have 100% of the window width.

I saw the `grow` prop on the `Stack.Item`. I assume I need to set `grow` only to main section.

The problem is that I can not make the `Stack` occupy the whole height of the window. It sets its size based on its children.

I think I have two possible solutions:

1) Set the height of the `Stack` based on window height. Also make its height a state, so that when the window height changes, change the `Stack` height.

2) Do the high level layout directly in CSS/HTML, e.g using flexbox. Use `Stack` only for in-section layouts.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/WVdjVb) to demo your requirements of the layout using `Stack`. It’s basically doing what you suggested in option 1. You can always look into option 2 but it all depends on the complexity of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Stack is an abstraction of Flexbox with a few nice things added in (like gap). So if Flexbox is sufficient to build your page layout, Stack will work perfectly.

If you need a more complex, 2 dimensional layout, you might want to normal css Grid for each region, and then layout content via Stack inside of each of those regions.